Change react-native-ui-library sectionWheelPicker style?
So im using RNUILIB to make a time selection menu for an alarm app, however i can't seem to change the background color of the SectionsWheelPicker Component

const TimePicker = ({ onTimeChange }) => {

  const hours = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => ({ label: (i + 1).toString(), value: i + 1 }));
  const minutes = Array.from({ length: 60 }, (_, i) => ({ label: i.toString().padStart(2, '0'), value: i }));
  const periods = [{ label: 'AM', value: 'AM' }, { label: 'PM', value: 'PM' }];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SectionsWheelPicker
        sections={[
          { style: {flex: 1 }, items: hours, index: hours.findIndex(h => h.value === selectedHour) },
          { style: {flex: 1 }, items: minutes, index: minutes.findIndex(m => m.value === selectedMinute) },
          { style: {flex: 1 }, items: periods, index: periods.findIndex(p => p.value === selectedPeriod) }
        ]}
        onValueChange={handleTimeChange}
        activeTextColor={"#000"}
        inactiveTextColor={"#535353"}
        numberOfVisibleRows={3}
        textStyle={{ fontFamily: 'reg' }}
        itemHeight={80}
        faderProps={{ height: 0 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

i tried putting a style on the parent view that has backgroundColor: "#242424" and tried putting the same style on the SectionsWheelPicker and it didn't work
